# DirectX 3D Primitives equivalent in WPF?

Tags: wpf, directx

There are Primitives types enum in DirectX that contains Point, Line, LineList, LineStrip, Triangle, TriangleFan, TriangleStrip...

I can find only Triangle in WPF 3D.

Then how to draw point, line , or wired object.

If I do not supply material then I cannot see anything

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into Path Geometry? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx

Comment: I am asking for in reference of WPF3D

Comment: Ohh Sorry about that comment then. in WPF 3D all objects are described in terms of triangles considering it is the most granular geometry to describe a planar surface. You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112034/drawing-3d-lines-in-wpf So drawing a line we need to set Triangle indices to represent a line. In the model you need to define the MeshGeometry with tirangle indices representing as a line.

Answer (score 0):

For 3-D WPF uses Mesh Geometry to define the shapes of displayed objects.

Charles Petzold has an introduction here [Foundations: 3D Mesh Geometries, MSDN Magazine April 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163449.aspx)